# Function that maps 0 to 1 to 255 to 255

Tags: calculus

Trying to come up with a function that takes a sequence of numbers from 0 to 1 and outputs a number between 255 and 255. That is, it goes from 255 to 0 and 0 to 255. I'f I come up with a solution I'll post it but in the meantime I could use some help on this.

Comment: I think he wants f(0)=f(1)=255 and f(1/2)=0, you can use f(x)=$255(2x-1)^2$

Comment: Yep close enough! A few minutes ago I came up with abs(2x-1). I guess it's one of those questions you ask and the answer comes to you.

Comment: Is this about subnet masking?

Comment: Nope, just animation related. Opacity goes 0 to 255 in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly but there are an infinite number of functions that have the property you're describing. Examples:

$\left|-510x + 255\right|$ [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%E2%88%92510x%2B255%7C%2C+x%5Cin+%5B0%2C+1%5D&x=0&y=0)

$1020\left(x - \frac 1 2\right)^2$ [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1020%28x%E2%88%921%2F2%29%5E2%2C+x%5Cin%5B0%2C1%5D&x=7&y=6)

(Mark's example from the comments:)

$\displaystyle\frac{255(\cos 2πx+1)}{2}$ [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=255%2F2+%28cos%282%CF%80x%29%2B1%29%2C+x%5Cin+%5B0%2C+1%5D&x=0&y=0)

Comment: Can't blame you for not understanding, I'm not particularly eloquent when asking math related questions in english. Though your answer would work I ended up going with abs(2x-1) for the moment. Thank you.

Comment: Now I really don't understand! :) What does $|2x-1|$ have to do with $255$?

Comment: Woops,  |2x−1| * 255.

Comment: $\dfrac{255}{2}\left(\cos\left({2\pi}x\right)+1\right)$ might work more nicely depending on the application since the slope is flat at 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. Do you mean 255 and 256? Do you mean 0.01 becomes 255.01, 0.2 becomes 255.2, 0.99 becomes 255.99? And then the 255+a bounces between 255+a and 0+a?

Now that I see you've posted  abs(2x-1)*255, it makes sense.

Another way to do it is something like

```
shiftBits = max( ceil(x),1 )  or
shiftBits = x == 0 ? 1 : ceil(x);

value =  shiftLeft(0x7F, shiftBits)
```

I'm not specifying the programming language because I dont know what you're using.